# Bochner-Minlos for moment-generating functions?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, stochastic-processes, quantum-field-theory, statistical-physics

It is well-known that the Bochner-Minlos theorem characterises measures on duals of nuclear spaces by their characteristic functions. Is there a similar version for moment-generating functions?
I have a sequence of measures admitting moment-generating functions and I wish to prove something like convergence of the moment-generating functions implies convergence of the measures. But it is unclear to me, what kinds of convergences I should look at and in particular what properties I have to demand from the limiting function.

Comment: A good question, but one would need a lot more specific details in order to be able to help you. What are these measures, and on what space? What is the extent of your control of the moment generating function? How come you can't do a little bit of analytic continuation and get a hold of the characteristic function instead? What do you know already, and what references did you look at? etc. etc.

Comment: So many questions :D Well, the measures indeed live on the space of tempered distributions as in your answer. They correspond to QTFs in the sense of Osterwalder-Schrader but are regularized - but this is more of a goal than an à priori feature. I obtain the moment-generating functions rather indirectly and I only really have control over the Fenchel conjugate of the limiting object. To be honest, I would not know how to perform an analytic continuation in this setting at all which is of course another reason to ask this question - begging there could exist a simple answer.

Comment: Thanks for the infos, although you didn't say which references you were following. I  an ideal world, there would be an article which proves the theorem you need. Here is a metatheorem: if your moment generating functions are well defined and analytic in a complex neighborhood of the origin and if you convergence is reasonably uniform in that neighborhood, then you have weak convergence of probability measures. I don't think you will find this in the literature which, in this area, is a giant mess. I'm confident this is true, meaning, if I had a new PhD student I could assign this as...

Comment: ...something to work out and turn into a quick research paper in their first two months of PhD work. Now even if the ideal theorem is not yet available, there are some hacks one can already do in specific situations (that's why I asked for specific details). For example one can replace $i\varphi(f)$ in the exponential featuring in the characteristic function by $z\varphi(f)$ where $z$ is a small complex number. For fixed $f$, this is about uniform convergence of holomorphic functions of one complex variable. Not scary at all. This approach, in the spirit of the Cramer-Wold device,...

Comment: ...can give you pointwise convergence of characteristic functions far away from the origin. However, one still needs other arguments to prove the continuity at the origin of the full infinite-dimensional limit characteristic function. I will edit my answer with a specific worked out example that I lectured about in a graduate course I taught a while ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While waiting for more context around the question, one can already mention the main definitions and tools for this topic.

I will assume the space on which these probability measures live is the space $\mathscr{S}'(\mathbb{R}^d,\mathbb{R})$ of temperate real-valued Schwartz distributions on $\mathbb{R}^d$.
It is the $\mathbb{R}$-vector space given as the topological dual of the
space $\mathscr{S}(\mathbb{R}^d,\mathbb{R})$ of real-valued Schwartz functions.
The latter carries the usual Fréchet topology.
Recall that a subset $A\subset\mathscr{S}(\mathbb{R}^d,\mathbb{R})$ is bounded iff, for all continuous seminorms $\rho$ on $\mathscr{S}(\mathbb{R}^d,\mathbb{R})$
$$
\sup_{f\in A}\rho(f)\ <\ \infty\ .
$$
The space $\mathscr{S}'(\mathbb{R}^d,\mathbb{R})$ is equipped with its canonical/standard topology, namely the *strong topology* which is the locally convex topology defined by the seminorms
$$
\varphi\ \longmapsto\ \sup_{f\in A}|\varphi(f)|
$$
where $A$ ranges over all bounded subsets of $\mathscr{S}(\mathbb{R}^d,\mathbb{R})$. Finally, $\mathscr{S}'(\mathbb{R}^d,\mathbb{R})$ is turned into a measurable space thanks to the Borel $\sigma$-algebra for the strong topology.

Let us call a function $\Phi:\mathscr{S}(\mathbb{R}^d,\mathbb{R})\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ *a* characteristic function iff it satisfies the following three conditions:

1. $\Phi(0)=1$,
2. $\Phi$ is continuous,
3. for all $n\ge 1$ and all $f_1,\ldots,f_n$ in $\mathscr{S}(\mathbb{R}^d,\mathbb{R})$, the matrix $(\Phi(f_i-f_j))_{1\le i,j\le n}$ is Hermitian positive semidefinite.

There is no harm in changing 2) to just continuity at the origin.
Now for a Borel probability measure $\mu$ on $\mathscr{S}'(\mathbb{R}^d,\mathbb{R})$, we define *the* characteristic function *of* $\mu$ as the function $\Phi_{\mu}:\mathscr{S}(\mathbb{R}^d,\mathbb{R})\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ defined by
$$
\Phi_{\mu}(f)=\int_{\mathscr{S}'(\mathbb{R}^d,\mathbb{R})}e^{i\varphi(f)}\ d\mu(\varphi)\ .
$$

**Theorem:** (Bochner-Minlos)
The map $\mu\mapsto\Phi_{\mu}$ is a bijection from the set of Borel probability measures on $\mathscr{S}'(\mathbb{R}^d,\mathbb{R})$ to the set of characteristic functions.

The weak convergence of probability measures on $\mathscr{S}'(\mathbb{R}^d,\mathbb{R})$ is defined in the same way as for any other topological space.

**Definition:** Let $\mu$ be a Borel probability measure on $\mathscr{S}'(\mathbb{R}^d,\mathbb{R})$ and $(\mu_n)_{n\ge 1}$ be a sequence of Borel probability measures on $\mathscr{S}'(\mathbb{R}^d,\mathbb{R})$. We say that $\mu_n$ *converges weakly to* $\mu$ iff
for all bounded continuous functions $F:\mathscr{S}'(\mathbb{R}^d,\mathbb{R})\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$,
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_{\mathscr{S}'(\mathbb{R}^d,\mathbb{R})}F(\varphi)\ d\mu_n(\varphi)
=\int_{\mathscr{S}'(\mathbb{R}^d,\mathbb{R})}F(\varphi)\ d\mu(\varphi)\ .
$$

We now have an analogue of *Glivenko's Theorem*.

**Theorem:**
The setting being the same as for the previous definition, the weak convergence of $\mu_n$ to $\mu$ is equivalent to the pointwise convergence of characteristic functions, namely,
$$
\forall f\in\mathscr{S}(\mathbb{R}^d,\mathbb{R}),\ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\Phi_{\mu_n}(f)=\Phi_{\mu}(f)\ .
$$

Finally, we also have an analogue of the *Lévy Continuity Theorem*, when one does not *a priori* have a candidate for the weak limit.

**Theorem:**
Let $(\mu_n)_{n\ge 1}$ be a sequence of Borel probability measures on $\mathscr{S}'(\mathbb{R}^d,\mathbb{R})$. The existence of a Borel probability measure $\mu$ such that $\mu_n$ converges weakly to $\mu$, is equivalent to requiring that

1. for all $f\in\mathscr{S}(\mathbb{R}^d,\mathbb{R})$, the limit $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\Phi_{\mu_n}(f)$ exists, and
2. the function $\Phi$ defined by $\Phi(f)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\Phi_{\mu_n}(f)$ is continuous at the origin.

I'll stop here this attempt at a *formulaire raisonné*, for now, but there are also other useful results like $\mathscr{S}'(\mathbb{R}^d,\mathbb{R})$ being a Radon space as well as Prokhorov's Theorem.

---

**Edit: Mar 14, 2021**

Finally, got a little bit of time to explain the explicit example I mentioned.

Consider the Ising model in one dimension with zero magnetic field, nearest-neighbor coupling function $J>0$ and inverse temperature $\beta$, in infinite volume. This is a Borel probability measure $\mu$ on $\{-1,1\}^{\mathbb{Z}}$, with corresponding expectations denoted by $\langle \cdots\rangle$.
Pick, once and for all, your favorite number $L>1$ and for $M\in\mathbb{N}$, define the map
$$
\begin{array}{cccc}
\Gamma_M: & \{-1,1\}^{\mathbb{Z}} & \longrightarrow & \mathscr{S}'(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})\ \\
 & \sigma=(\sigma_x)_{x\in\mathbb{Z}} & \longmapsto & 
 L^{-\frac{M}{2}}\sum\limits_{x\in\mathbb{Z}}\sigma_x \delta_{L^{-M}x}
\end{array}
$$
where $\delta_z$ denotes the Dirac distribution located at $z$.
Similarly to my answer to

[A set of questions on continuous Gaussian Free Fields (GFF)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/364470/a-set-of-questions-on-continuous-gaussian-free-fields-gff?rq=1)

this map is well defined, continuous, and therefore Borel measurable. This allows you to define the push-forward measure $\mu_M:=(\Gamma_M)_{\ast}\mu$. It turns out that when $M\rightarrow\infty$ the measure $\mu_M$ converges weakly to a multiple of white noise on $\mathbb{R}$. This is a special case of a theorem of Newman for FKG spin systems, but it is a good exercise to do it using, in a completely explicit way, characteristic functions/moment generating functions via the control of what is happening in a complex neighborhood of the origin.

First recall that the correlation functions vanish for odd number of spins and are otherwise given by
$$
\langle \sigma_{x_1}\sigma_{x_2}\cdots\sigma_{x_{n}}\rangle=e^{-m(|x_1-x_2|+|x_3-x_4|+\cdots+|x_{n-1}-x_n|)}
$$
if $n$ is even and $x_1<x_2<\cdots<x_n$. The mass or rate of exponential decay is $m:=-\log\tanh(\beta J)$.

Now if we have a complex-valued test function $f\in\mathscr{S}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C})$, it holds that
$$
\int_{\mathscr{S}'(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})}
e^{i\varphi(f)}\ d\mu_M(\varphi)
=\left\langle
\exp\left[i\sum_{x\in\mathbb{Z}}\sigma_x g_x\right]
\right\rangle
$$
where $g=(g_x)_{x\in\mathbb{Z}}\in \mathcal{s}(\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{C})$ is a discrete test function, with rapid decay on the lattice $\mathbb{Z}$, given by $g_x=L^{-\frac{M}{2}}f(L^{-M}x)$.
Since we work with complex-valued test functions, the difference between characteristic functions and moment generating function is moot and amounts to deciding to absorb the $i$ into the test function or not. We will keep it out.

Using the cluster expansion techniques from [my article on the Spin-Boson Model](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00023-011-0103-6), one can show after a bit of work that for all complex function (not necessarily of fast decay) $g:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$, in the domain $||g||_{\ell^1}<\frac{1}{2e}$,
$$
\left\langle
\exp\left[i\sum_{x\in\mathbb{Z}}\sigma_x g_x\right]
\right\rangle
=\exp(\mathcal{F}(g))
$$
where
$$
\mathcal{F}(g)=\sum_{p\ge 1}\frac{1}{p!}
\sum_{\substack{x_1,\ldots,x_p\in\mathbb{Z}\\ y_1,\ldots,y_p\in\mathbb{Z}}}
\prod_{i=1}^{p}\left[
-\mathbf{1}\{x_i<y_i\}e^{-m|x_i-y_i|}\tan(g_{x_i})\tan(g_{y_i})
\right]
$$
$$
\times\left(
\sum_{\substack{H\subset\wedge^2[p]\\ H\ \text{connects}\ [p]}}
\prod_{\{i,j\}\in H}\left[-\mathbf{1}\left\{
\ [x_i,y_i]\cap[x_j,y_j]\neq\varnothing\ 
\right\}\right]
\right)\ .
$$
The notation is as follows. $[p]:=\{1,2,\ldots,p\}$, $\wedge^2[p]$ is the set of two-element subsets $\{i,j\}$ of $[p]$. The subset $H$ is a graph (or edge set thereof) required to connect the vertex set $[p]$. $\mathbf{1}\{\cdots\}$ is the indicator function of the enclosed condition. The intervals $[x,y]$ are integer intervals inside $\mathbb{Z}$.
Finally, the sum giving $\mathcal{F}(g)$ converges absolutely provided one keeps the sum over $H$ inside the modulus. One can write this bound in a combinatorially explicit way too.

With the above result one can show that for $f\in\mathscr{S}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C})$ such that
$4eK||f||_{L^{\infty}}||f||_{L^{1}}<1$,
$$
\lim\limits_{M\rightarrow \infty}
\int_{\mathscr{S}'(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})}
e^{i\varphi(f)}\ d\mu_M(\varphi)
=
\exp\left[-\frac{K}{2}\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)^2\ dx\right]\ .
$$
Here the constant $K$ is related to the susceptibility and is given by $K=\frac{1+e^{-m}}{1-e^{-m}}$.

Now take $f\in\mathscr{S}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$, a real-valued test function but this time with no limitation on its size.
For $z\in\mathbb{C}$, let
$$
G_M(z)=\int_{\mathscr{S}'(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})}
e^{iz\varphi(f)}\ d\mu_M(\varphi)\ ,
$$
which is well defined and analytic in an open horizontal strip around the real axis. The bound for $\mathcal{F}$ shows that $G_M(z)$ is uniformly bounded in $z$ and $M$ on every compact subset of the strip. The Vitali-Porter Theorem then gives pointwise convergence on the real line, and the Lévy Continuity Theorem finishes the job of proving that we weakly converge to $\sqrt{K}$ times white noise.

Comment: So far, this is a really nice summary of essential features. Much appreciated!

Comment: @iolo: I edited my answer to give an example of application. The issue about characteristic function vs moment generating function reduces to the one-dimensional situation (Cramer-Wold strikes again). A good reference for the latter is the book "Characteristic Functions" by Eugene Lukacs.